# Matrix notation: Does empty space means a bunch of zeros?

Tags: matrices, notation

I don't understand what is meant with the following notation:

http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/uploads/db1409/470/f060d496ac7c29c8.png

I think this means that the

first row = 4 2 0 ... 0
second row = 1 4 1 0 ... 0
third row = 0 1 4 1 0 .. 0
etc.

Is this correct ?

Comment: I think that's a reasonable assumption. What is the context for this notation? Does this assumption make sense in the proof/computation given? Could you perhaps post it?

Comment: @AWertheim The complete question doesn't make sense to me yet, but you could have a look if you want:
http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/uploads/db1409/471/1721351a3760fdb5.png

Comment: Yes, the empty space is filled with zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Very likely, unless the surrounding text suggests some other pattern for the middle rows. Because that's what the $\dots$ mean: keep going with the pattern; and what that pattern is should somehow, implicitly, be clear to the reader.